# Compare present date to previous/next date

Tags: javascript, date, string-to-datetime

Suppose i have a string like ,

```js
let oldDate = "30-1-2022";
let presentDate = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
console.log(oldDate,presentDate)
```

Now my question is how can i check wich Date is the biggest Date.

Comment: The statements you have written are invalid JS or at least not doing what you expect: oldDate will contain -1993 for example because no quotes and you have two `= =` signs where you only want one

Comment: I fixed your string and made you a [mcve]

Comment: `const gtToday = date => { const [oDD, oMM, oYYYY] = date.split("-"); const now = new Date(); now.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0); return new Date(oYYYY, oMM - 1, oDD, 15, 0, 0, 0) > now;}`